# Reload init.el without restart, with CEDET

Tags: init-file, cedet

CEDET prevents me from doing `M-x load-file` `init.el` with the error:

```
progn: CEDET Version 2.0 already loaded.
```

How do I modify my CEDET load line to load conditionally? The current line looks like:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest method

Assuming you're not worried about it not being available because the file is missing/in error

```
(ignore-errors
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el"))
```

This will bypass the error and allow you to continue loading.

Require instead of load

Looking at `cedet-devel-load.el` on https://github.com/emacsmirror/cedet/blob/master/cedet-devel-load.el the last line is `(provide 'cedet-devel-load)`.

This means you can replace your load line with:

```
;; If you haven't already added it to load path above
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/cedet")
(require 'cedet-devel-load)
```

This will use the library and ensure you do not have to worry about it being loaded more than the initial time.